# Cannot post question; "improperly formatted code"

Tags: support, edits, markdown, quality-filter

I'm getting

> [image]

when my question ***should*** be valid. This is ***only*** an issue on Stack Overflow. It works on Code Review, for example.

Here is what the output looks like:

> [image]

Here is the code triggering the error:

> [image]

I have seen and know for a fact you should be able to use `<pre><code>` instead of four spaces. I can't use four spaces because I want to bold `print` and `println` for emphasis.

Per **[this meta stackexchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/306202)**, what I am doing should be possibe:

> [image]

I've read many meta threads on people who get the error, but they all have to do with using ### headers or something of the effect. I don't see this here.

- Removing the language tag doesn't fix it
- Removing the `<strong>` doesn't fix it

**Does anyone know how to get `<pre><code>` working on SO?**

Comment: **Don't use html when you don't need it**.

Comment: @Braiam Why. The point is this ***should*** be working on Stack Overflow and it's not. I know my use case is borderline pointless, but it's the fact it's not working period.

Comment: No. The point is that you should use markdown whenever is possible, and only using html when you already are using markdown. People tend to post their HTML instead of code, which is why the message reads "Your post **appears to contain code that is not properly formatted**".

Comment: As I said though, I can't use markdown for what I want.

Comment: Also, don't use images when you don't need it ;).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Subjective ;)

Comment: `<pre><code>` works fine if the code doesn't form the bulk of your post. The filter isn't smart enough to realize that you're posting properly-formatted Java code and instead thinks you're posting unformatted HTML.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Nice find. Possibly post this as an answer?

Comment: Dude, you're @insane! ;) Couldn't resist.

Answer (score 7):

You can use plain markdown for what you want:

---

Compare

```java
void printDescription() {
    System.out.print(description);
    //         ^^^^^
}
```

against

```java
void printDescription() {
    System.out.println(description);
    //         ^^^^^^^
}
```

---

Source:

```java
Compare

<!-- language-all: lang-java -->

    void printDescription() {
        System.out.print(description);
        //         ^^^^^
    }

against

    void printDescription() {
        System.out.println(description);
        //         ^^^^^^^
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I like that. Actually brings more emphasis than bolding. Still though, the original question does remain.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I misread the question. I thought it was asking "Why doesn't this work", rather than "how can I make this work."